# How to add multiple pictures as a new user?

Tags: support, new-users, images

I am unable to add more than two pictures as my reputation is not high enough, but my question will not be clear without those pictures. Please suggest a course of action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you could patch the pictures together in a graphics program (GIMP, MS Paint, PhotoShop) and upload them.

But, are you sure you need more than two pictures? Things like source code and error messages should *not* be in pictures (as people won't be able to search for them), and you should always strive to make a [**Minimum**, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you boil the problem down to the essential minimum, we might already be able to help with only two pictures. Or even no pictures at all.

Alternatively, find two questions/answers that need editing, have them approved and you're already at 10 reputation, which lifts the [restriction to two images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user).

Comment: I haven't added any source code the pictures show the steps I have taken window by window. I can't merge the pictures as I have added captions to them.

Comment: @TanmayKulkarni OK, good, but I don't understand why you can't use a graphics program to copy them into one larger picture. This should be fairly easy. Or have you written the captions in your question? Perhaps add some small captions (e.g. "Step 1", "Step 2") in the picture, and refer to them in the question.